# How to get grey preview from camera using OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm a newer on OpenGL ES 2. I think I need to add some logic in camera's previewCallback, but I have no idea how to do that. What I need is a black-and-white preview. That will be great if you can provide an example. I read android doc but still have no idea, please help. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html

```
camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
//do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data format is yuv420sp commonly， first 1/2 length of data is Y data, this can be taken as your grey data.